# Calculating large power of a number

Tags: c++, c, bignum

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#define M 1000000007
using namespace std;

long long int power(int a,int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        return 1;
    else if(b==1)
        return a;
    else if(b%2==0)
        return power((a*a)%M,b/2);
    else
        return (power((a*a)%M,b/2)*a)%M;
}
```

In this function when I pass a=2, b>31, it always returns 0.for b=31 i got 147483634.can you tell where the problem is?

or can you tell another method for calculating large powers of a number.

Comment: 42 would be a better choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `(a*a)%M`, a*a probably overflows before computing the remainder. And starting with 2, the overflow producing 0 doesn't surprise me. You need to work with a type able to represent (M-1)*(M-1), i.e. 1000000012000000036 while `int` is commonly limited to 2147483647. `long long` (standard in C since 99 and C++ since 11, common extension elsewhere) is guaranteed to work.

Comment: can u plz tell why on starting with 2, the overflow produces 0?

Comment: @anubhav, the most common behavior in case of overflow is to drop the high order bits. For a power of two, the result is 0. The other common overflowed value is INT_MIN (for 2^31).

Answer (score 0):

Under `<cmath>` there's `pow(x,y)` in which x is the base and y is the exponent. x^y.

[Reference here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

Comment: This is computing a modular integer exponent.  A floating point pow() over the real numbers won't work.  As Daniel points out though, it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

When `a` is an `int`, `a*a` uses `int`-sized arithmetic.  Try `a*(long long)a` instead, to use wider arithmetic that won't overflow.